# ClearCase: Versioning at file level

Tags: versioning, clearcase

I have a perculier problem about how to maintain a clearcase project.

This project is a xml schema repository where each schema has a version. This repository is common and is used by all the apps in the enterprise. From clearcase prespective the project has a single component.

Now the apps can be using different versions of the schema(s). So we are trying to figureout a way to setup the project in such way that a project can have a baseline of what versions of these files are included in a build.

The only way we know of how to do this is to create a component for each schema or group of schemas and create a stream for each app to include the components they use. But that would result in too many components.

Has anyone dealth with something like this before? We are prepared to restructre the whole project if necessary, so we are open to any idea.  Thans for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind a UCM component is to reference a *coherent* group of file, i.e all files within a UCM component are labeled (baselined) even if only one of them if modified.
The life-cycle of those files is common, and they are used as a whole.

In your case:

- each file (xml schema) can evolve on its own
- the granularity is at file level (and not group of files)

You can group those files in one component, but each of your project will then need to extract its own version of the relevant file, through [extended path names](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_version_path.htm).

That means:

- your project reference the latest baseline of the "XML schema repo" UCM component
- it extract from that component the relevant version of the various xlm files it needs
- and copy those version in a private (non-versioned) directory

Comment: Thanks a lot, VonC.  A tedious solution but so is the our need.